# Scatter Plot after groupby result

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, multi-index

I have a dataframe that I have used groupby function in Pandas, as the following:

| Remarks | Area | PIC | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Special | 101 | P1 | 1000 |
|  |  | P2 | 1100 |
|  | 102 | P3 | 1050 |
|  |  | P4 | 1200 |
|  |  | P5 | 1000 |
| Regular | 101 | P6 | 1500 |
|  |  | P7 | 1200 |
|  |  | P8 | 1300 |
|  | 102 | P9 | 1100 |
|  |  | P0 | 1050 |

Is it possible to create a scatter plot for the grouped result?
I've tried to unstack(), but the PIC rows became the column.

The purpose of the plot is to compare whether each PIC in the Area with Remarks Special is similar in term of Average with PIC in Regular remarks.

Comment: With the `level` argument of `unstack`, you can control which row becomes a column. Is `.unstack(level=0)` working for you?

Comment: By reseting the index (and make it normal columns) (`pd.reset_index`), can't you use `seaborn.scatterplot` with `hue=remarks`. You'd obtain a scatter plot with point `Special` and `Regular` shown in different colors (with proper associated legends)

Comment: Hi @Andrea , the .unstack(level=0) is working to move the Remarks back to column. But, when i tried to plot using seaborn, it couldn't recognize the value name, i.e. column. Please advise.

Comment: Hi @AntoineMagron , I managed to use your advise in my code. That was really helpful. Thank you very much